# In SymPy, how might I build a function that alters an input expression?

Tags: expression, sympy

I'm brand new to sympy and to computer algebra systems. I'd like to create a function that can take in an expanded expression and return an expression in which powers are replaced by 1. For example, if the function is named `unpower`:

```
>>> unpower(x*y**3 + x**2)
x*y + x
```

**Is it possible to do this?** If so, **where might I start in the documentation in order to learn how to do it?** Tips/advice welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more advanced replacement exercise since you want to match exponents of any power. All SymPy objects have properties; the most basic property is `args` which tells you what the arguments of the object are.

```
>>> (x**y).args
(x, y)
```

Sometimes different args have names like `base` and `exp` for the args of `Pow` and you can query an object to find out what it is:

```
>>> (x**y).exp
y
>>> (1/x).is_Pow
True
```

The `replace` method -- see `help(Basic.replace)` -- is good for your needs because it can target only powers

```
>>> (x*y**3 + x**2).replace(lambda _: _.is_Pow, lambda _: _.base)
x*y + x
```

But you might want to keep the sign of the exponent, else

```
>>> (x/y).replace(lambda _: _.is_Pow, lambda _: _.base)
x*y
```

So maybe

```
>>> from sympy import sign
>>> unpow = lambda e: e.replace(lambda _: _.is_Pow, lambda _: _.base**sign(_.exp))
>>> unpow(x**3/y**2)
x/y
```

Comment: Thanks for that clear and educational answer, @smichr!